# VBA to delete rows based on zeros in third column

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have tables built in word that I'd like to remove the entire row if the number in the third column is zero. This will be for a mail merger with around 200 tables. This is the first time I'm using VBA, so any help would be appreciated

this is code I am using:

```vb
Sub DeleteRowsWithZeroInThirdColumn()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rngCellText As String
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Loop through each table in the document
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        ' Loop through each row in the table in reverse order
        For i = tbl.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            ' Get the text from the third cell in the row
            rngCellText = Trim(tbl.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text)
            
            ' Check if the third cell contains only "0"
            If Len(rngCellText) = 1 And rngCellText = "0" Then
                ' Delete the row if the condition is met
                tbl.Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

However, I am getting a 5941 error in this code. `rngCellText = Trim(tbl.cell(i, 3).Range.Text)`. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```vb
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rngCellText As String
    Dim i As Long
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        For i = tbl.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            ' Each row should contain at least 3 cells
            If tbl.Rows(i).Cells.Count >= 3 Then
                ' remove non-printable char Chr(13) & Chr(7)
                rngCellText = Trim(Replace(Replace(tbl.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text, Chr(7), ""), Chr(13), ""))
                If rngCellText = "0" Then
                    tbl.Rows(i).Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next tbl
End Sub
```